# How can I get the data of $photos->tags?

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, object, facebook-graph-api

In Graph API › Photo, I'm using below script to get Photo attributes

```
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    if($response=='')   {   echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";    }

    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $fb_photo_id='10150361640936173';
    $graph_url_photos = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $fb_photo_id . "?access_token=" 
    . $params['access_token'];
    $photos = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url_photos));
    }  


    ("token " . $params['access_token']);
    echo $photos_id=$photos->id; echo "</br>";
```

Question: How can I get the data of `$photos->tags`?

Comment: This is my first accept, thanks a lot. Besides, I would be grateful if you can also help to give script like above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196145/how-can-i-get-the-data-of-photos-tags

Comment: 1) you are linking to the same question 2) each **entry** in this page has a comment section so you should have these comments on *my answer* not here. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you access it:

```
<?php

// ... your code here...
if(!empty($photos->tags)) {
    foreach($photos->tags->data as $tag)
        echo "ID: {$tag->id}<br />Name: {$tag->name}<br />X: {$tag->x}<br />Y: {$tag->y}<br />Created on: {$tag->created_time}<br /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this page to test for Graph API calls:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

And for your example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10150361640936173

You will see that "tags" structure is like this:

```
"tags": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1696691267",
        "name": "黃柏淇",
        "x": 64.375,
        "y": 80.2619,
        "created_time": "2011-11-07T09:12:22+0000"
      },
      {
        "id": "1705329218",
        "name": "Austin Ng",
        "x": 80.4543,
        "y": 48.0512,
        "created_time": "2011-11-07T09:12:22+0000"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: ID: 1696691267
Name: 黃柏淇
X: 64.375
Y: 80.2619
Created on: 2011-11-07T09:12:22+0000

ID: 1705329218
Name: Austin Ng
X: 80.4543
Y: 48.0512
Created on: 2011-11-07T09:12:22+0000